# domain with og access issue

Tags: organic-groups, domain-access

My site uses the Domain and OG modules.

I created the following content types: Group and  Group Post. I added OG visible field on Group, and OG content visible field on Group Post. Then, I created a group node, set the visibility as private. I created a group post node, and set the visibility as private.

I log out, and verified that anonymous users can see both.

I tried to build a new site with Drupal, and OG. When I follow the above steps, the result is right: Anonymous users can't see the two nodes.

I googled the issue, and found [Visibility Access issue and Domain Access](https://drupal.org/node/1070046).

It seemed that the Domain and OG modules can't work together.

Does anyone have any solution?

Answer (score 1):

https://drupal.org/project/domain_access_bridge

This module creates a working interplay between the Domain Access suite, one {access control} module (e.g. Organic Groups, Content Access, Taxonomy Access) and eventually the Workflow module.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this too. I ended up building a module that provides exactly this functionality, to restrict groups by domain. I also identified the need for an easy way to provide

- custom styling (CSS)
- behaviors (JS)
- and templates (template suggestions) per domain.

There are instructions as well as youtube video walkthroughs.

https://github.com/ejanus/og_domain_access